# Private org wide settings set to private affect MC Connected data availability

Tags: marketing-cloud, org-wide-defaults

I have a Salesforce Org with Org-wide settings for Account&Contacts set to PRIVATE, even for System Administrator users (no role hierarchy setup).
I would like to connect the org to Marketing Cloud via MC Connect, but I'm worried on whether Accounts&Contacts data will be available for the Synchronized Data Extensions.

Has anyone encounter this? Appreciate your input.

Comment: Normally you would give administrator users the "access all data permission" to "overwrite" sharing settings. Is this applicable in your case?

Comment: I am not sure what is your goal - do you want this data to be available in SFMC, or not?

Comment: Thank you both for the replies. Yes, I want to be able to see records in Marketing Cloud once connected. Just wanted to confirm that I am correct and if the Default org-wide is set to private, this will not be possible. Thank you again.